# How crosscompile c program for win32 with mingw32 on linux

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I need to compile my program for Windows 32 bit. But I'm using files from the /sys/ directory and mingw32 says it can't find them.

```
        x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=c99 -g -ggdb -c ./client.c -o ./client.o -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -static-libgcc
        x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=c99 -g -ggdb -fPIC -o ./client ./client.o -static-libgcc
```

```
ingvar@ingvar:~/Downloads/UDP$ make x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=c99 -g -ggdb -c ./client.c -o ./client.o -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -static-libgcc
./client.c:11:10: fatal error: sys/poll.h: No such file or directory 11 
#include <sys/poll.h> 
^~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. make: *** [Makefile:8: client] Error 1
```

I tried to search on the Internet and read the documentation tried to use a virtual machine.

Comment: *"I'm using files from the /sys/ directory and mingw32 says it can't find them"* What files do you mean? Can you show the errors?

Comment: ingvar@ingvar:~/Downloads/UDP$ make
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=c99 -g -ggdb -c ./client.c -o ./client.o -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L -static-libgcc
./client.c:11:10: fatal error: sys/poll.h: No such file or directory
   11 | #include <sys/poll.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:8: client] Error 1

Comment: Those files are not available on Windows. You need to use something else. There's also Cygwin, which might have it, but A - I don't think you can cross-compile with it, and B - rewriting the app to use something else is still preferrable.

Comment: Although you CAN use gcc to cross-compile a Linux app on a Windows workstation ... the EASIEST approach is to simply install gcc and build your app locally, on a Linux host.  There are many ways to do this, including : a) [Linux dual boot](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/dual-boot-linux-and-windows-11), b) use a VM like [VBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or c) use Microsoft [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)